# Override settings.py for testing

Tags: python, testing, settings

I have my project settings in settings.py file. There are database names, user names, host names etc. defined there. In project files I do `import settings` and then use the constants where needed like `settings.HOST`. For unit testing I would like to use different settings. How should I override the settings? I am not using django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new file - say `local_settings.py` in which you override the specific settings for you debugging and testing purposes.

Then you add this block at the end of your `settings.py`

```
# Override these settings with local settings if such a file exists 
try:
     from local_settings import * 
except ImportError as e:
     pass
```

You should add `local_settings.py` to your `.gitignore` file to exclude this file from version control (if you are using git).

This is the standard way Django does this by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest way would be to move your `settings.py` to another folder for safekeeping and then make a new one, and edit that for debugging.